# Edit single pixel in ASCII grid

Tags: raster, dem, ascii

I converted DTM Data from LAZ to ASCII.

Now I got some artifacts with an obviously wrong cell values[image].

Is there a simple way to edit just a single cell?

I tried looking for the cell value in Notepad++, but there are several cells all over the area that have a similar value, so I can't find my cell easily.

Any ideas?